# How to call a named xslt template on a specific node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a very uniform input XML that I need to transform to quite a customized XML.
To do this, I am trying to invoked names templates at different places of the XSL. My issue is that it is not possible to select a node when calling a template, resulting in very long and redundant code such as this (simplified example to illustrate the issue):

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <workspace>
       <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/data_set[@id='id1']" />                  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/data_set[@id='id2']" />                  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/data_set[@id='id3']" />                  
       </data>
    </workspace>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id1']">            
    <xsl:call-template name="attribute">                            
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_value1'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_value2'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id2']">            
    <xsl:call-template name="attribute">                            
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_other_value1'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_other_value2'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id3']">            
    <xsl:call-template name="attribute">                            
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_third_value1'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_third_value2'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="attribute">
    <xsl:param name="id" />
    <xsl:param name="type" />       

     <!-- Write the attribute node -->
    <attribute attribute_id="{$id}" attribute_value_type="{$type}">         
        <xsl:for-each select="data_point">
            <element>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@key" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$type}"><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></xsl:attribute>                                          
            </element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </attribute>            

</xsl:template>
```

Is there a better way to do this to avoid all this redundancy? What I would want is to write something like this (but this is not valid XSLT) since you cannot do a select in a call-template.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <workspace>
       <data>
        <xsl:call-template name="attribute" select="/data/data_set[@id='id1']">                         
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_value1'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_value2'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="attribute" select="/data/data_set[@id='id2']">                         
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_other_value1'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_other_value2'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="attribute" select="/data/data_set[@id='id3']">                         
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'some_third_value1'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'some_thrid_value2'" />
        </xsl:call-template>           
       </data>
    </workspace>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
      <data_set id="id1">
         <data_point value="1" key="4"/>
         <data_point value="2" key="5"/>
         <data_point value="3" key="6"/>
      </data_set>
      <data_set id="id2">
         <data_point value="1" key="4"/>
         <data_point value="2" key="5"/>
         <data_point value="3" key="6"/>
      </data_set>
      <data_set id="id3">
         <data_point value="1" key="4"/>
         <data_point value="2" key="5"/>
         <data_point value="3" key="6"/>
      </data_set>
</data>
```

Sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<workspace>
    <data>
        <attribute id="some_value1" type="some_value2">
            <element id="4" some_value2="1"/>
            <element id="5" some_value2="2"/>
            <element id="6" some_value2="3"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute id="some_other_value1" type="some_other_value2">
            <element id="4" some_other_value2="1"/>
            <element id="5" some_other_value2="2"/>
            <element id="6" some_other_value2="3"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute id="some_third_value1" type="some_third_value2">
            <element id="4" some_third_value2="1"/>
            <element id="5" some_third_value2="2"/>
            <element id="6" some_third_value2="3"/>
        </attribute>
    </data>
</workspace>
```

Comment: The issue would be much better illustrated if it contained an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Well,,it's still an enigma because we don't see what the called template does. Are those parameters completely arbitrary? Or could they be somehow derived from the `@id`?

Comment: Is it possible to see the call-template? Maybe we can strike this out. So the redundancy will be less as well. But what we can't see, we can't change.

Comment: Parameters and even templates can vary quite a lot depending on the id.

Comment: @user3124206 Perhaps you should use a lookup to determine them. BTW, your example shows the same template being called for every id.

Comment: yes, indeed: i wanted to illustrate the verbosity problem which happens already with one template. Essentially, the idea is for the input XML to be completely static in terms of schema but the XSLT could result in a fairly exotic XML consumed by an API downstream. An input data_set with the same id could also potentially be reused multiple times in different section of the XSL.

Comment: @user3124206 XSLT is inherently verbose. There are techniques to reduce code repetition, but it is difficult to advise without seeing the full picture. --  "*An input data_set with the same id could also potentially be reused multiple times in different section of the XSL*." That's what `mode` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's important that the called template is given the context of the matched `data_set`, then I would suggest you do it along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <workspace>
       <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data_set[@id='id1' or id='id2' or id='id3']" />                  
       </data>
    </workspace>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data_set">            
    <xsl:call-template name="attribute">  
        <xsl:with-param name="id">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id1'">some_value1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id2'">some_other_value1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id3'">some_third_value1</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id1'">some_value2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id2'">some_other_value2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@id='id3'">some_third_value3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you're using XSLT 1.0. Could be a little less verbose in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something along these lines + using `mode` that you suggested and getting a result I am reasonably satisfied with in terms of verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your question is a common use case. What I normally do in this case, is to use matching templates with modes to retrieve the information, that I need and then pass that information to named templates.

This not the most obvious way of doing it. But after a few times it becomes relatively intuitive that splitting the problem into these two steps is not a  bad idea. It is more in line with the conceptual model of XSLT. XSLT is a functional programming language. In functional programming languages side effects and interaction to the context happens in a very controlled manner and not arbitrarily in the program code. Having separate modes for these templates makes this very clear.

My solution is the following XSLT 2.0 code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <workspace>
       <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/data_set"/>
       </data>
    </workspace>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id1']" mode="determine_attribute_params">
    <id>some_value1</id>
    <type>some_value2</type>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id2']" mode="determine_attribute_params">
    <id>some_other_value1</id>
    <type>some_other_value2</type>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data/data_set[@id='id3']" mode="determine_attribute_params">
    <id>some_third_value1</id>
    <type>some_third_value2</type>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/data_set">            
    <xsl:variable name="attribute_params">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="determine_attribute_params"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="attribute">                            
        <xsl:with-param name="id_and_type" select="$attribute_params" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="attribute">
    <xsl:param name="id_and_type" />   

     <!-- Write the attribute node -->
    <attribute id="{$id_and_type/id}" type="{$id_and_type/type}">         
        <xsl:for-each select="data_point">
            <element>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@key"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$id_and_type/type}"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>                                          
            </element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </attribute>            

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See again the template `attribute`, what I mean with reducing interactions with the context. The version of that template that you were asking for is something that transforms existing XML. That is a side-effect-y thing. The version that I propose creates new XML. That has no side effect. XSLT wants you not to mix this. Therefore it does not allow you to have matching templates with names.

Actually, what I am writing is not 100% true. XSLT always creates new XML. But in my opinion it often feels like transforming existing XML. And this is often a pitfall. So what I am saying is more a mental model that helps you to understand, that you have to make a decision whether you want to convert something or create something new.

Note that with XSLT 1.0 my code will not work as is. It may require small modification, because the way how variables can be used in `select` is different in XSLT 1.0. (It has to be converted to a node-set.)

One thing is also worth mentioning. See the template `/data/data_set`. It determines the data that is to be passed to `attribute`. But it does not even know what this data is. It just knows, there is something and it gives it the name `attribute_params`. But only the templates that have `attribute` in their name or in their mode know the details. This is often considered as very good style. It creates an abstraction layer, that helps you to make the whole process easier to understand. The ideas of functional programming and XSLT is that the programming language enables, motivates or even force you to chose this style of working, so that you nearly automatically come to a good design and well maintainable code.

Although the template `/data/data_set` has access to `attribute_params` it cannot manipulate them, because in XSLT variables are immutable. For `/data/data/_set` it is nearly impossible to break the contract, that is established between the templates `mode="determine_attribute_params` and the template `name="attribute"`. Such layered concepts can make your code very reliable.

The other answer for this question is also good and probably a bit easier to understand. There is nothing wrong with it. What I tried to illustrate in my answer is, that there is an alternative and that the decision how you solve your problem actually matters. But it depends on your concrete situation if this is the case or not.

Comment: *"In XSLT 1.0 it is not legal to use variables in select expressions.*" That's an incorrect statement. The reason your code cannot work in XSLT 1.0 is that the variable is a result-tree-fragment and needs to be converted to a node-set before it can be processed further. (Withholding opinion on the actual code.)

Comment: P.S. If you're posting code that requires XSLT 2.0, you may want do declare `version="2.0"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.